# directionsService.route does not return data to bind div

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am doing some js to get directions panel with asp.net

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom:7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
}


function calcRoute(lat,lan) {
    var InitialOrigin =  document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FESearchListingControl1_txtHide').value;
    //var InitialOrigin = document.getElementById("txtHide").Value;
    var technopark = new google.maps.LatLng(8.5572357 ,76.87649310000006 );

    var split = InitialOrigin.split(',');
    var latFrom = parseFloat(split[0]);
    var lanFrom = parseFloat(split[1]);
    InitialOrigin= new google.maps.LatLng(latFrom,lanFrom);
    var to = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lan);
    //  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    //  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:InitialOrigin,
        destination:to,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('something went wrong',status);
        }
    });
}
```

I debugged with crome browser and could find that the the line

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
```

did not return anything,the debugger just jumped to the last closing brace.
The debugger never entered this if statement

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
else
{
    console.log('something went wrong',status);
}
```

This was working before,and i was getting the directions panel before,is there some restrictions with google ?

Comment: What values are you getting for latFrom & lanFrom??

Comment: @davidstrachan:latFrom,lanFrom = 8.7072357 ,76.15649310000006

Comment: lat &lan do not seem to be defied for     var to = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lan);

Comment: @davidstrachan:that comes as arguments from the function calcRoute(lat,lan)

Comment: Where are you calling calcRoute(lat,lan) It is not called in your code

Comment: @davidstrachan : its called in one button onClick='calcRoute(8.7072357 ,76.15649310000006)';